# What is the best way to fill the pdf form with pdftk in python django

Tags: python, django, pdftk

I have two forms

1. One for uploading the PDF templates of unfilled form
2. Other for submitting the filled data

Now my team leader told me that i have to save the file for template case but when user submits the filled form then i need to extract the data from pdf file with pdftk and then when user wants to download it i have to refill the form with that data.

Currenlly i am using

`pdftk sample.pdf dump_data_feilds`

and i am saving that fields to the database.

now i don't know how can i regenerate the pdf from the template with that data.

how should i proceed

Answer (score 2):

You need [FDFGEN](https://github.com/ccnmtl/fdfgen) to create FDF from from the fields

You can generate PDF from the FDF previously generated with `PDFTK`

`pdftk form.pdf fill_form data.fdf output output.pdf flatten`